# Question (again) on eclipse debugging java apis

Tags: java, eclipse, security, jakarta-ee, jce

I have a question that pops up occusionally.
I am trying to debug some jdk apis using eclipse.
I have tried:
1) Using the jre inside jdk (containing the jdk src) as the jre to use
2) Adding the jdk src as a separate project and add reference from my project to the jdk project.
I started debugging.
I got into the jdk code but only up to a certain point.
Then I got the "Attach Source" editor.
The part of code I am trying to debug is part of java's pkix apis that uses the JCE provider architecture.
So for example I do

```
Certificate generateCertificate(fin);//I go into the code
```

then I step into

```
return certFacSpi.engineGenerateCertificate(inStream);
```

And I get "Source Not Found Editor"
I see that the class called is:

```
public class sun.security.provider.X509Factory extends java.security.cert.CertificateFactorySpi
```

But I can not seem to find the package sun.security.provider in the jdk src.
Isn't all src available from SUN? Am I doing something wrong in my environment setup?

Any input is highly welcome

Answer (score 2):

The full source code is distributed as separate jar file, but it's a little bit outdated (6u23): http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/

But you can also download the openjdk sources, that contain also the source of the sun specific classes.